# Build shared library with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, shared-libraries

I would like to build a shared object/shared library (.so) by using Visual C++. I chose project compile type: static library

However this way it builds a .lib file. Is it even possible to build unix shared librarys with Visual C++?

Comment: Microsoft's tools only output Microsoft binaries; you could probably configure the IDE to use a different toolset, but I think that would be a lot of work.

Comment: @Luke: You are right, for Windows I need dll. If you want, post your answer and I accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows name for a shared library is Dynamic Link Library (DLL).

In "Win32 Application Wizard" choose Application Type: **DLL**

Comment: i can build c# language DLL file use in android application as  Shared Object(.so) library?